# How to say "in a certain respect" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, adverb

How does one say the adverbial phrase "in a certain respect" or "in certain respects" in Latin?

For example, would

> whatever under a certain condition is such-and-such, is such-and-such **in a certain respect**; but whatever lacks that condition, is simply such-and-such

be a good translation of

> *quod sub conditione est tale, **secundum quid** est tale; quod autem absque conditione est tale, simpliciter est tale*
> <sub>—St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Summa Theologica* I-II q. 6 a. 6](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS006.html#FSQ6A6THEP1) arg. 3</sub>

?

Comment: Can you give some example sentences?

Comment: @cmw added an example

Comment: @Geremia FWIW, Aristotle and Aquinas (among others) would think of your example as a *per se* predication.

Comment: @brianpck Maybe. Do you have a better example?

Comment: @Geremia Aquinas gives a good modification of your example in a Christological passage from his Sentences commentary: Man is an animal *per se*, but Christ is an animal *secundum quid*, i.e. *inquantum est homo*.

Comment: @brianpck Are you referring to [_Super Sent._ lib. 3 d. 10 q. 1 a. 1 qc. 2 s.c. 1.](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/snp3006.html#8690)? Isn't _simpliciter_ (not *per se*) the antonym of _secundum quid_?

Comment: @Geremia *per se* is more often contrasted with *per accidens*, but the two map pretty closely to the *simpliciter/secundum quid* distinction. See, for instance, *De Ver.* q. 17, a. 4: "Quia quod per se est, simpliciter est; quod autem per accidens, secundum quid." My original point was pretty limited: "Man is an animal" is a *per se* predication that is true *simpliciter*: in fact, Aquinas would even call it "self-evident" (*per se notum*) because it is a predication of a part of the definition (the genus) of "man."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An extremely common term in **medieval** Latin, often used in a philosophical context, is **secundum quid**, i.e. "with respect to something." Obviously, [*secundum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsecundum) is used as a preposition here.

It is usually contrasted with something that exists *per se*, i.e. "in itself," or *simpliciter*, i.e. "simply speaking."

You can find hundreds of examples in the [Index Thomisticus](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age). Here's one representative case:

> Praeterea, omne quod dicitur **secundum quid**, originatur ab eo quod est simpliciter et absolute. (*Super Sent.*, lib. 1 d. 2 q. 1 a. 2 s.c. 2.)

My translation:

> Furthermore, everything that is said **in a certain respect** originates from that which exists simply and absolutely.

Comment: "_Secundum quid_" is what I was thinking, too, but is there also "_secundum [quos/quas/quae](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quis#Declension)_" ("in certain respect**s**")?

Comment: No, I've never seen that usage. "Secundum quid" is more like "in a qualified way": it either is or it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

Without more context, it's difficult to know precisely what you need to say. However, **quodam modo** means "in a certain manner", which could correspond to "in a certain respect" depending on context. Similarly you could use **quadam ratione**.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use **aliquatenus**. According to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=aliquatenus) (II) it can mean "To a certain degree" and "in some respects"

So as it seems to remark the *restrictive* flavor, I may say *aliquatenus* is indeed a good fit here, but maybe only aliquatenus-ly so.

> Philistus,... ut multo inferior, ita aliquatenus lucidior  (Philistus, as he was inferior, so in some respects brighter).

*Homo aliquatenus animal est*: To a certain degree man is an animal.

Comment: _Hom**e**_ is the Catalan translation of _homo_. Cf. Cat. "L'home és fins a cert punt un animal".

Comment: @Mitomino, fixed :)

Comment: The example sentence is so strange I can't decide whether I'm confused because of its entirety or specifically because of how *aliquātenus* is used o_o It reads like "2+2 in some respect equals 4" to me - basically it can't be used to qualify an either-or definition, there must be a sliding scale, and equalling 4 or being an animal, tree or insect doesn't admit of one in most cases.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian, would *non sine causa dicitur hominem homini lupus esse; homo enim aliquatenus animal est* makes more sense?

Comment: Not really, because *homō animal est* is simply unqualifiably true, like *lupus animal est*, *saxum inanimum est* or *apis bēstiola est, item animal. **Animam habet? Animal est.*** How can there be an *aliquātenus* to it? I think there must be some English-language interference here, where 'animal' has the "bad" meaning **bēstia,** but even there I hardly imagine sensibly making such a statement because it's either a definition dependent on the technical definition of 'animal'—how can a great ape be more or less an animal?—or the "bad" metaphorical use that doesn't allow qualification either.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across the following sentence in the fourth Catilinarian oration ([Cicero, In Catilinam 4,22](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/cat4.shtml#22)):

> Quamquam est **uno loco** condicio melior externae victoriae quam domesticae, quod hostes alienigenae aut oppressi serviunt aut recepti [in amicitiam] beneficio se obligatos putant; qui autem ex numero civium dementia aliqua depravati hostes patriae semel esse coeperunt, eos cum a pernicie rei publicae reppuleris, nec vi coercere nec beneficio placare possis.
>
> *Although **in one point** the circumstances of foreign triumph are better than those of domestic victory; because foreign enemies, either if they be crushed become one's servants, or if they be received into the state, think themselves bound to us by obligations; but those of the number of citizens who become depraved by madness and once begin to be enemies to their country,—those men, when you have defeated their attempts to injure the republic, you can neither restrain by force nor conciliate by kindness.*

([Translation by C. D. Yonge.](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0019%3Atext%3DCatil.%3Aspeech%3D4%3Achapter%3D10%3Asection%3D22))

This does not seem to be a particular common expression, although the meaning "matter, point" for *locus* is documented. On the other hand, you cannot go wrong by riffing off Cicero.